# Why is my code always receiving a null pointer exception when I have binded the element in to it? I am using Java in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio, nullpointerexception, text-to-speech

I am receiving java.lang.NullPointerException, although I have binded the element correctly.

Tried to check the ID of the element, it matches, but still I receive the same exception.

```
MainActivity.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);


    //Text to Speech
    tts = new TextToSpeech(this, this);

    speakButton = findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    speechText = findViewById(R.id.speechText);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
    // End

    loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

TranslatorFragment.java
public class TranslatorFragment extends Fragment {

public Button speakButton;

public TranslatorFragment(){
    //Empty Constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.translator_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
    speakButton = view.findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
}
```

}

It should be running fine, But I am receiving the java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: are you using a fragment or an activity?

Comment: my button is on a fragment.xml

Comment: You must add this code in onViewCreated() function.  can you show me whole code??

Comment: how can I show you the code? I am a newbie here

Comment: edit your question and put your frament .java code there.

Comment: my question is edited.

Comment: have I correctly done what you have said?

Comment: I have answered your question.  Please check and let  me know.. if there is any error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You button code should be declared in you fragment not in you activity as the button is in your fragment.xml. As you are accessing the button in onCreate  method of the activity it will give nullpointer exception  because you fragment's view is not  yet rendered.The best practice is to access the view in onViewCreated function of your fragment.

```
MainActivity.java
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
loadFragment(new HomeFragment());

    BottomNavigationView navigation = findViewById(R.id.navigation);
    navigation.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(mOnNavigationItemSelectedListener);
}

TranslatorFragment.java
public class TranslatorFragment extends Fragment {

public Button speakButton;

public TranslatorFragment(){
    //Empty Constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.translator_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

     //Text to Speech
    tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);

    speakButton = findViewById(R.id.speakButton);

    speechText = findViewById(R.id.speechText);

    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
    // End
}
void speakOut(){
}
```

Comment: how about my OnInit() method and OnDestroy() method? what am I going to replace it with? because btw I am working on a text to speech. can I put it in a fragment?

Comment: yes... you can put your OnInit() code in onCreate function of fragment and OnDestroy is same in fragment.

Comment: Am I going to literally put it on onCreateView? I am really sorry for having so many questions, I am a beginner in Java and Android programming.if I put it in an onCreate method, it has a parameter which is Int status. if I am also going to declare it, error will pop that says unreachable statement.

Comment: Its ok. Can you mail me whole code of your activity and fragment so i can properly edit the code and share it with you.

Comment: I have already solved it. Thank you for the solution that you have given me. The only thing that I needed is to implement the TextToSpeech.OnInitListener on my fragment.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to implement TextToSpeech.OnInitListener in the project and make the public variables to be private.

```
public class TranslatorFragment extends Fragment implements TextToSpeech.OnInitListener{

private Button speakButton; // public Button speakButton;
private TextToSpeech tts;
private EditText speechText; // public EditText speechText;

public TranslatorFragment(){
    //Empty Constructor
}

@Override
public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    return inflater.inflate(R.layout.translator_fragment, container, false);
}

public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
}

@Override
public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

    tts = new TextToSpeech(getActivity(), this);
    speakButton = view.findViewById(R.id.speakButton);
    speechText = view.findViewById(R.id.speechText);
    speakButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            speakOut();
        }
    });
}

private void speakOut(){
    String text = speechText.getText().toString();
    tts.speak(text, TextToSpeech.QUEUE_FLUSH, null);
}

public void onInit(int status){
    if(status == TextToSpeech.SUCCESS){
        int result = tts.setLanguage(Locale.getDefault());

        if(result == TextToSpeech.LANG_MISSING_DATA || result == TextToSpeech.LANG_NOT_SUPPORTED){
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Language not supported!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        } else {
            speakButton.setEnabled(true);
            speakOut();
        }
    }
    else
    {
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Initilization failed!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

public void onDestroy() {
    if(tts != null){
        tts.stop();
        tts.shutdown();
    }
    super.onDestroy();
}
```

}